# Format line begin and end in Visio 2007 db model

Tags: database-design, visio

I have a db model with relations. All of them by default are with triangle in one end and nothing in the other. 
When I right click the line -> format -> line -> and format both ends to be with triangles I hit apply but nothing happens. The line remains the same.
How I can format the line so both ends are with triangles?

Comment: Why would you want to do that anyway? The direction of FKs is very important for the meaning of the database model - if you suddenly changed the graphical representation to no longer correspond to the meaning of the model, that would effectively make the model "unreadable".

Answer (score 0):

To change arrow display options, use Database -> Document -> Display options. You can choose "Relational" or "IDEF1X" display options, display options for "crow feet", "cardinality", etc.

You are not supposed to modify formatting of connectors directly; instead, choose the notation you want to use, and Visio will show/format connects according to that notation.

In principle you can override that, and forcefully format connectors they way you want (the connector shapes are in fact [protected using shapesheet](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/prevent-changes-to-visio-drawings-HA001085830.aspx)), but, once more, you are not supposed to do that.